# access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "execute")

Tags: java, security, applet

I am beginner.it is first applet that i writing

i want run exe application with applet

java code

```
 package appletexample;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Welcome extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        String execommand = "C:\\windows\\notepad.exe" ;
        try {
            Process proc =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execommand) ;
        }
        catch(IOException ieo) {
            System.out.println("Problem starting " + execommand) ;
        }
    }
}
```

java.policy.applet

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

i run this code in eclipse `Run As->Java Applet` worked and opened NotePade
but when `Export->Jar File(with .classPath,.project,java.policy.applet)`
and use in

Html

```
<applet archive="test.jar" code="appletexample/Welcome.class"  width=550 height=300>
```

in firefox say error access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "execute")?
how can fix this problem?
[image: firefox first]
[image]
[download my java and Html code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZQO92LSOT4bDIxUEF5SW1ra1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If this is a new project, consider dropping applets altogether. Use JNLP instead.

Comment: i am beginner,which applets drop?what is JNLP?please more explain

Comment: Just search around for JNLP; 10 minutes of searching and reading should get you started.

Comment: JNLP is for run exe application?

Comment: Read about JNLP here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html

Comment: read JNLP and does not understand anything,please help me solve this problem with this way(applet),it is first and last java applet ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you just want to practice how to write a applet.
For development purpose,  you can create a keystore and then use it to sign your applet.jar.

Go: Start Menu > Execute > cmd.exe

Input:

```
cd /
keytool -genkey -dname "cn=CN, ou=OU, o=O, l=L, st=ST, c=C" -alias mykey -keypass mypass -keystore mystore -validity 3650 -storepass mypass
jarsigner -keystore c:\mystore -storepass mypass C:\path\to\applet.jar mykey
```

Then:

Refresh your HTML page.

Comment: thanks for help but say error Your security have blocked a self-signed application from running

Comment: You can add the URL of this application to Exception Site List, which is located under the Security tab of the Java Control Panel. See http://java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml#selfsigned

Comment: thanks,after create keystore say error security when add url to exception site,applet worked,

Answer (score 2):

As beginner you should start with something much much simpler. When you play with Applets not all security rules apply.  But when you come to real world (Browser in your case or, in other terms, sandbox) security rules are in force to prevent your code from harming the host computer.

What you are doing - you are running some program on the client computer when the client opens your web page with an Applet.  That what viruses do.  People will not want to allow it.

Of course you can the use [Signed Applet](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2014/01/16/still-using-applets-sign-them-or-else) approach or other ways to run program on another computer, but is it your goal?  If it is to learn basics, then run easy stuff.  Eventually, you will understand [JNLP (Java Web Start)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) and other methods useful for you and your clients.