# How can I run a program on the client side with firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

i use this script for run application on client side

```
function RunEXE(prog) {
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    oShell.Run('"' + prog + '"', 1);
} 
RunEXE('1.exe');
```

this code worked on IE but in Firefox does not worked for `ActiveXObject`.

Question 
what is equivalent of this code for Firefox?
or

how can convert this code for firefox?

what is  equivalent of `ActiveXobject` in firefox?

how can user `WScript.Shell` in firefox?

no matter i can change all permission on client side browser

Comment: You don't. A browser does not have the right to run executables. Your code does not work in recent versions of IE unless you change permission settings to be wide open for all kinds of attacks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie) might help

Comment: @Juan Mendes no matter i can change all permission on client side browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490713/how-to-run-a-local-exe-in-my-firefox-extension?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you create an applet and run code like the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.exe", null, new File("."));
```

If you want to be able to pass arguments to the java applet, you'll have to learn about communication between JavaScript and Java in applets. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

This is totally untested, and you may have to get your applet signed and deal with SecurityManager https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

Comment: i try use applet but ;( ;( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966200/access-denied-java-io-filepermission-execute and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962645/how-can-import-package

Comment: very bad security manager and JNLP ,i hate, i spend one week for this.